# How to setup Eclipse Andmore

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, andmore

I have just downloaded Andmore and restarted Eclipse, but now Eclipse is asking me where the SDK is. Where is the Andmore SDK? How do I setup Eclipse Andmore?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably asking for the Android Sdk. To enter the location in eclipse select window>preferences>Android...and in the dialog box under Android Preferences browse to the directory under the  SDK Location text box.
Android Sdk is available if you do not have it. Andmore is a plugin for eclipse that allows you to easily program for your android phone.